# Query String Error or Code Error?

Tags: php, html, string, url

I am trying to write some code that will simply return a value of someone's name, followed by 3 test scores. In my head, the code should look simply like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Scores</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

  echo "<p>",$_GET["name"],"</p>";
  echo "<p>",$_GET["test1"],"</p>";
  echo "<p>",$_GET["test2"],"</p>";
  echo "<p>",$_GET["test3"],"</p>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, whenever I type in the URL: `http://localhost/phpassignment1.php?name=john&test1=88&test2=74&test3=100`

It only returns the value of the name. Is there any reason why I am not getting the 3 test scores to be echoed onto the page?

Comment: This should work fine. Error is somewhere else. `print_r($_GET)`, what do you see?

Comment: @u_mulder so why the `.` answer worked.

Comment: Because error was somewhere else

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Copying and pasting the code must have fixed another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP syntax is wrong for joins. You need to use `.` instead of `,`.

```
echo "<p>",$_GET["name"],"</p>";
echo "<p>",$_GET["test1"],"</p>";
echo "<p>",$_GET["test2"],"</p>";
echo "<p>",$_GET["test3"],"</p>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<p>" . $_GET["name"] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $_GET["test1"] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $_GET["test2"] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $_GET["test3"] . "</p>";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seriously? this should help?

Comment: @obsidian Age This worked. Thanks!

Comment: This does not make a difference at all...

Comment: @jeroen For some reason it printed all of the test scores out using "."  I do not have an explanation why though.

Comment: @jeroen sure it does. I saw a next to the same question yesterday where they used commas instead of dots

Comment: @Dday By replacing that block you must have fixed the real problem as well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not really, you can separate the values with comma's and that works fine: https://eval.in/729312

Comment: @jeroen depends on their php version

Comment: @Fred-ii- It might, but I've never heard anything about that nor does the manual say anything about it. I'd be interested in references if you have any. Note that you can't use parenthesis when you pass multiple arguments, perhaps that was the issue yesterday?

Comment: @jeroen am sure that would produce something to the effect of `unexpected ,` etc.